# Is it appropriate for me to answer questions?

Tags: discussion

I am a Westerner, and only slowly learning about the Quran.

I don't even know the difference from a *Muslim* to a *Believer*.

Would it be allowed to answer questions all the same, from *my* point of view?

How to mark my answers to be known that I am not ... well, how to put it, borne or raised inside the Muslim world?

Comment: In my short time here I have seen questions that look like desperately looking for personal advice. How to go about tham?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers should provide the point of view of Islam, supported with citations to Quran, Ahadith and works of scholars. They should not be based on your personal point of view. This is Islam.SE not Ask_GyroGearloose.SE and it is not a discussion forum. If you do not know the correct answer to a question then you should not post it.

However if you do post a proper Islamic answer then there is no need to mark whether you are born or raised in a Muslim country as that is irrelevant. You can even be a non-Muslim living on Mars for all we care, as long as your answer conveys what Islam teaches it is acceptable.

Comment: "This is Islam.SE not Ask_GyroGearloose.SE" +1 for this!

Comment: So I will restrict what I have to say on aspects outside of Islam to comments, as I did previously.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the site is to share knowledge of Islam. If you have knowledge of Islam, regardless of how you obtained it, it's welcome here.

However, it's important to remember that we are a pluralistic site catering to *all* flavours of Islam, many of which conflict over major points of doctrine. We are rather strict regarding the sharing of subjective opinions, speculation, or anything that attempts to promote one interpretation or belief system as better than any other, else everything is likely to devolve into pointless arguing; there's already enough of *that* on the Internet, we don't need more here.

If your personal opinions are valuable and relevant to the answer, they can be included but should be clearly labeled so they're not mistaken for actual doctrine or scholarly interpretations. But the bulk of the answer should still consist of clear objective facts and knowledge, not opinions, and if such inclusions result in unnecessary argumentation over tangential details they may end up removed.